# Avoid dynamic SQL generation when calling stored procedure on SQL server from R/DBI/ODBC

Tags: r, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc, dbi

Using the profiler on `SQL Server` to monitor a `stored procedure` call via `DBI`/`odbc`, shows that dynamic SQL / prepared statement is generated :

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),...)
dbGetQuery(con, "EXEC sp_helptext 'sys.sp_addlogin';")
```

Results on `SQL Server` in:

```sql
declare @p1 int
set @p1=2
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,NULL,N'EXEC sp_helptext ''sys.sp_addlogin'';'
select @p1
```

For database safety & performance we disabled dynamic SQL calls, so that I would like a direct call:

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'sys.sp_addlogin';
```

Not sure if the dynamic SQL overlay is generated by `DBI` or by the `odbc` driver.
Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it is just how ODBC "does its thing". PyODBC operates in a very similar way. (See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkxWX.gif) I used in an old comment of mine about how it parses table type parameters.)

Comment: `sp_addlogin` Shouldn't be using that old, deprecated procedure in the first place.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for feedback : this indeed points to ODBC driver. Didn't find options to modify this behaviour.

Comment: @SMor, sp_addlogin is just an example for reproducibility, I'm using a custom stored procedure

Comment: @Larnu, see answer for R, perhaps similar in Python. Thanks again for your feedback which helped to search in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in `odbc` package documentation : [direct execution](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/12/odbc-1-2-0/#immediatedirect-execution).

> The odbc package uses Prepared Statements to compile the query once and reuse it, allowing large or repeated queries to be more efficient. However, prepared statements can actually perform worse in some cases, such as many different small queries that are all only executed once.
> Because of this the odbc package now also supports direct queries by specifying `immediate = TRUE`.

This will use a prepared statement:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "EXEC sp_helptext 'sys.sp_addlogin';")
```

> declare @p1 int
> set @p1=2
> exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,NULL,N'EXEC sp_helptext ''sys.sp_addlogin'';'
> select @p1

This will execute the stored procedure directly:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "EXEC sp_helptext 'sys.sp_addlogin';",immediate = TRUE)
```

> EXEC sp_helptext 'sys.sp_addlogin';